# Making Ubuntu my only OS using WUBI

Tags: system-installation, windows-8, wubi

I have never used Ubuntu before.  I am currently running Windows 8 and have installed Ubuntu 12.10 using the wubi install kit.

My comp. will not recognize a DVD drive for now.

I want to destroy Windows 8, while keeping personal files, and make Ubuntu my only OS.

How do I do this?

---

The problem being that I cannot create a disk... So I am looking to accomplish a full install with only the use of wubi

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/47206

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is impossible. The WUBI runs from inside Windows. It creates a `virtual partition` in a big file inside `Windows partition` (such as C:). The bootloader is tricked to look inside the Windows partition for the Ubuntu partition that is actually a file.

By **destroy Windows 8** if you mean to reformat the Windows partition, then you will lose your Ubuntu installation as well. Without Windows and a Windows partition, there is no way to install WUBI.

Create a live USB either from within Windows by http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows OR from within Ubuntu:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Boot your computer from the USB stick and install Ubuntu **overwriting Windows and everything else.**

Before you do this, **make copies of all your personal data, music, photos, and whatever else you value.** in an external hard drive.

Hope this helps