# Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop on WIndows 8 64 bit

Tags: installation, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Windows 8 64 bit laptop, and I am wondering if when I start Ubuntu does it at all use Windows 8 to run?  I am new to linux and an looking for an alternative to Win 8.  Even though the warning states that installing Ubuntu via the windows installer is not supported in Win 8, it does work.  I have had some issues installing Google Chrome, but aside from that no issue.

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

BTW - Since my work uses Win 7, I feel I will always be a slave to it, but if it works great, then I am thinking of reformatting my HDD and giving the lion share of my SSD to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please clarify: Did you install Ubuntu using WUBI.EXE from within Windows 8?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/213516/making-ubuntu-my-only-os-using-wubi

Answer (score 0):

The WUBI runs from inside Windows. It creates a virtual partition in a big file inside Windows partition (such as C:).

GRUB bootloader is tricked to look inside the Windows partition for the Ubuntu partition that is actually a file.

So, wubi will use windows8 then when you are trying to access Ubuntu then in the back-end you are using or relying on windows partition.

Now, if you just want to use Ubuntu without depending on windows you have to format your hard disk.